# 'progress' property of OperationQueue not working in iOS 13

Tags: swift, progress-bar, ios13, nsoperationqueue

iOS 13 introduced the `progress` property in the `OperationQueue` class. At the same time Apple marked the `operations` and `operationCount` properties as deprecated which indicates they should not be used anymore for reporting progress on a queue.

My problem is that I cannot get the `progress` property to work as I expect it to work (which is basically out of the box). Also I could not find any documentation regarding this new property (other than that it now exists).

I tried to get it to work in a new SingleView project that has one `UIProgressView` on the main `UIViewController`. This sample is heavily inspired by https://nshipster.com/ios-13/.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

    private let operationQueue: OperationQueue = {

        let queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        queue.underlyingQueue = .global(qos: .background)

        return queue

    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.progressView.observedProgress = operationQueue.progress

        self.operationQueue.cancelAllOperations()
        self.operationQueue.isSuspended = true

        for i in 0...9 {

            let operation = BlockOperation {
                sleep(1)
                NSLog("Operation \(i) executed.")
            }

            self.operationQueue.addOperation(operation)

        }

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        self.operationQueue.isSuspended = false

    }

}
```

The console shows that the queue is running as expected (as a serial queue), but there is no movement on the progress bar.

Also KVO on the `progress` property directly does not work, so I suspect the `progress` property of the OperationQueue to be the cause of the problem rather than the `UIProgressView`.

Any idea what I am missing here? Or could it be a bug in iOS 13? The problem exists in the simulator as well as on an iPhone 6s Plus, both running iOS 13.3.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just received feedback from Apple about this. The documentation is currently well hidden in the header file NSOperation.h. Here is the extract for anybody who encounters the same problem:

> ```
> /// @property progress
> /// @discussion     The `progress` property represents a total progress of the operations executed in the queue. By default NSOperationQueue
> /// does not report progress until the `totalUnitCount` of the progress is set. When the `totalUnitCount` property of the progress is set the
> /// queue then opts into participating in progress reporting. When enabled, each operation will contribute 1 unit of completion to the
> /// overall progress of the queue for operations that are finished by the end of main (operations that override start and do not invoke super
> /// will not contribute to progress). Special attention to race conditions should be made when updating the `totalUnitCount` of the progress
> /// as well as care should be taken to avoid 'backwards progress'. For example; when a NSOperationQueue's progress is 5/10, representing 50%
> /// completed, and there are 90 more operations about to be added and the `totalUnitCount` that would then make the progress report as 5/100
> /// which represents 5%. In this example it would mean that any progress bar would jump from displaying 50% back to 5%, which might not be
> /// desirable. In the cases where the `totalUnitCount` needs to be adjusted it is suggested to do this for thread-safety in a barrier by
> /// using the `addBarrierBlock:` API. This ensures that no un-expected execution state occurs adjusting into a potentially backwards moving
> /// progress scenario.
> ///
> /// @example
> /// NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
> /// queue.progress.totalUnitCount = 10;
> ```

Comment: In Apple's published documentation, they state asynchronous operations should override `start()`. Is this incorrect?